# Cannot find KieModule by ReleaseId in OSGI environment

Tags: jboss, drools, kie

The exception we receive is:

https://gist.github.com/dvirgiln/59d1eb3feccf4f8ab83b

As you can see it is mainly:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: org.switchyard.kie:project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:97)

The code used is:

```
    MavenRepository repository = MavenRepository.getMavenRepository();
    repository.resolveArtifact(releaseId.toExternalForm());
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
```

The value of the releaseId (String) is: org.switchyard.kie:project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

KIE and drools libraries 6.2.0.CR3.

bundles added in the features:

wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-api/${version.org.eclipse.aether.aether-api}
        wrap:mvn:org.jbpm/jbpm-executor/${version.org.jbpm}$DynamicImport-Package=org.hibernate.*,javassist.*
        wrap:mvn:org.jbpm/jbpm-workitems/${version.org.jbpm}
        wrap:mvn:org.kie/kie-ci/${version.org.kie}
        wrap:mvn:org.kie.remote/kie-remote-client/${version.org.kie}
        wrap:mvn:org.kie.remote/kie-remote-common/${version.org.kie}
        wrap:mvn:org.kie.remote/kie-remote-jaxb/${version.org.kie}
        wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven/maven-settings-builder/3.2.2
        wrap:mvn:org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.19
        wrap:mvn:org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.17
        wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven/maven-settings/3.2.2
        wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven/maven-aether-provider/3.2.2
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-impl/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-spi/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-connector-basic/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-transport-file/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-transport-http/0.9.0.M3
        mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.3.2
        mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.3.5
        wrap:mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-transport-wagon/0.9.0.M3
        wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0

I've debug the code. The second line of the code above, resolve correctly the artifact.
 repository.resolveArtifact(releaseId.toExternalForm());

The problem I think is related to this method:

```
 private KieModule loadKieModuleFromMavenRepo(ReleaseId releaseId, byte[] pomXml) {
    return pomXml != null ?
           getInternalKieScanner().loadArtifact(releaseId, new ByteArrayInputStream(pomXml)) :
           getInternalKieScanner().loadArtifact(releaseId);
}
```

I checked the call to getInternalKieScanner and it is a dummy repository. That is the reason why the loadArtifact is returning null.

org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl$DummyKieScanner@25a291e6